# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.Client, 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CppSvc.Internal StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException

Tags: xcode, macos, xamarin, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

My OS is Windows 10, developing with Visual Studio 2019, XCode 9.4, and developing Xamarin Forms app.

When trying to connect Mac book Pro 13 (10.13.6), via Visual Studio 2019, I get this weird state where I am connected to MacBook (check the 'chain' under screen icon), but really I am not, as it does not appear in paired devices.

[image]

When running the app I get a single error that says `A remote error occurred in the connected Mac`
[image]

When I click on the message I get to a log and in it I see a lot of steps and four errors.

> 8  PkgDefManagement initialized   VisualStudio 2021/03/03 14:54:24.665

> 9  RootFolder
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\   VisualStudio 2021/03/03 >14:54:24.665

> 10  ShellFolder
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\

> 624 ERROR Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file
> or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.Client, Version=16.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\professional\common7\ide\commonextensions\platform\diagnosticshub\Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Package.dll
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.VsShellComponentModelHost
> 2021/03/03 14:54:41.666

> 625 ERROR Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file
> or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CppSvc.Internal, Version=16.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
> dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CodeAnalysis\Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeAnalysis.VCPlugin.dll
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.VsShellComponentModelHost
> 2021/03/03 14:54:41.673

> 781 ERROR StreamJsonRpc.RemoteInvocationException: Error enumerating
> over credential store.at
> StreamJsonRpc.JsonRpc.d__139`1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)at Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.PipeManager.<InvokeRpcFuncAsync>d__13`1.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)at
> Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.GithubAccountProviderClient.d__40.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)at
> Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.AccountProvider.GithubAccountProviderClient.d__44.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Connected.UserInformation.UserInformationPackage.d__11.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskLibraryHelper.<>c__DisplayClass32_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.VsTaskLibraryHelper.<>c__DisplayClass35_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception
> exceptionObject) RPC server exception:
> Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.GithubCredentialStorage.Interop.InteropException:
> Error enumerating over credential store.at
> Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.GithubCredentialStorage.Interop.Windows.WindowsCredentialStore.Enumerate(String
> filter)at
> Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.GithubCredentialStorage.GitHubCredentialStore.SearchAllCredentials()at
> Microsoft.Developer.IdentityService.GithubCredentialStorage.GithubCredentialStoreService.b__10_0()at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()    vs/identity/githubsso
> 2021/03/03 14:55:12.650

....

and then at the very bottom

> 914  Did not find item to promote   MruList 2021/03/03 15:26:46.494

> 915  Entering MruItemsStoreServiceDecorator.AddMRUItem. Item category:
> 335041a8-b61a-4e9f-b0fe-d42dfa193855, lpszItem:
> %UserProfile%\source\repos\StruebyPhotoApp\StruebyPhotoApp.Api\StruebyPhotoApp.Api.csproj|{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}|0,0|False
> CodeContainerTracing 2021/03/03 15:26:46.494

> 916 ERROR
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
> of an object.at
> Xamarin.Messaging.Windows.ErrorsManager.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0(IErrorItem
> item) in
> C:\A\1\36\s\src\Core\Xamarin.Messaging.Windows\ErrorsManager.cs:line
> 24at Clide.ErrorsManager.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.b__0(Object sender,
> EventArgs e) in
> E:\A_work\349\s\src\Clide.Core.Windows\Errors\ErrorsManager.cs:line
> 55at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Task.OnNavigate(EventArgs e)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Task.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsTaskItem.NavigateTo()at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorListPkg.Shims.ErrorListPackageEventProcessor.PreprocessNavigate(ITableEntryHandle
> entryHandle, TableEntryNavigateEventArgs e)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.TableControl.Implementation.TableControlEventManager.<>c__DisplayClass40_0.b__2(ITableControlEventProcessor
> p, ITableEntryHandle entry)at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.TableControl.Implementation.TableControlEventManager.<>c__DisplayClass60_1`1.b__0()at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.CallExtensionPoint(Object
> errorSource, Action call) --- End of stack trace from previous
> location where exception was thrown --- at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception
> exceptionObject)

and this is where it ends.

**What is going on? How do I debug this further?**

Comment: You could try to update the version of your Xcode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to get a Mac Book Air that had support for the latest macOS (High Spur) and latest XCode (12) and the Visual Studio and Mac book managed to connect.

So one potential solution would be to upgrade your hardware.